# Vibrational Question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring, vibrations, coupled-oscillators

A friend recently asked me this question, which I am not even sure how to comprehend...

Three masses are arranged at the vertices of an equilateral triangle and are connected by springs along the edges of the equilateral triangle. How many normal modes for vibration does this mass-spring system have?

Can someone point me to some articles that can help me comprehend what's happening?

Comment: Wait, what is unclear about this question?

Comment: A online search for "normal modes"+"equilateral" produces a dozen explanations of how to find the normal modes for this specific case. What isn't clear about these resources?

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of [Normal modes of the 3-mass-spring system](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/282014/normal-modes-of-the-3-mass-spring-system?rq=1)

Comment: @Dude156 Can the masses move in three dimensions, or only in the plane of the triangle?